# Can I say 「うれしかったことは ○ ものです」 where ○ is not in past tense?

Tags: grammar

I came across the following exercise in my Japanese textbook:

[image: Exercise]

As regards the point ③, I wonder whether I can answer things such

とてもうれしかったことは**日本は給料が高い**ものです。

If not, **there would be any other expression in present tense to be used right before ものです in the sentence above?** What I came up with sounds really clunky to me, to be honest.

The point is that so far, the textbook I use has not introduced any other grammar point with 〜ものだ aside from the following one which uses present tense sentences and, moreover, this grammar point is presented *in the same chapter* than the conflictive exercise:

[image: grammar point]

But, searching the Internet I came up with the following grammar point to express ["used to do 〜" by using Verbた + ものです](https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n3-grammar-%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A0-mono-da/) that I think fits in ③ much better, as it is used to express a past situation and うれしかった is also in past tense. **Is it correct to say something like the following sentence?**

> とてもうれしかったことは**子供の頃ホッケーをした**ものです。

However, if that's the case, how come I am expected to use a grammar I have not been introduced to before in my textbook? It makes me feel I am missing something here. Maybe another use of 〜ものだ different than the two presented above?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> とてもうれしかったことは日本は給料が**高いもの**です。
>   とてもうれしかったことは子供の頃ホッケーを**したもの**です。

Both sound incorrect to me, I'm afraid. In both sentences, you use こと, not もの:

> とてもうれしかったことは、日本は給料が高**かったこと**です/高**いこと**です。
>   <sup>［うれしかった**こと**］＝［給料が高かった**こと**］
>
>   Sentence structure: 「［文＋こと］は［文＋こと］だ。」</sup>
>
> とてもうれしかったことは、子供の頃ホッケーを**したこと**です。
>   <sup>［うれしかった**こと**］＝［ホッケーをした**こと**］
>
>   Sentence structure: 「［文＋こと］は［文＋こと］だ。）」</sup>

---

To use もの in 「とてもうれしかったことは～～ものです」, I can only think of something like...

> とてもうれしかったことは、**時が経っても忘れないもの**です。
>   <sup>［うれしかったこと］is the object of 忘れない. The ものだ indicates 本来そうだと思われること（本性・当然）.
>
>   「［うれしかったことは(<**を**)忘れない］＋［ものだ］。」
>
>   Sentence structure: 「文＋ものだ。」</sup>
>
> とてもうれしかったことは、**ずっと心に残るもの**です。
>   <sup>［うれしかったこと］is the subject of 心に残る. The ものだ indicates 本来そうだと思われること（本性・当然）.
>
>   「［うれしかったことは(<**が**)心に残る」＋［ものだ］。」
>
>   Sentence structure: 「文＋ものだ。」</sup>

Comment: I am trying to figure out why your last final sentences make sense with もの but mines don't. Is it because they regard feelings or more generally one's state? would you be kind to elaborate a little bit more? Thank you very much!!

Comment: And, coming back the original question, why is it「 **うれしかった**ことは、時が経っても忘れないものです。」instead of 「 **うれしい**のは、時が経っても忘れないものです。」? Is it similar as when saying よかった for things you think are good even now, despite using the かった form?

Comment: In my last two sentences, the sentence structure is 「Sentence+ものだ。」, it's made of 「『うれしかったことは時が経っても忘れない』+『ものだ』」, うれしかったこと is the object of 忘れない, and the ものだ indicates 本来そうだと思われること, whereas in my first two sentences, the sentence structure is 「『Sentence+こと』は『Sentence+こと』だ。」. This cannot be rephrased 「『Sentence+こと』は『Sentence+もの』だ。」

Comment: 「嬉しか**った**ことは、時が経っても忘れない（with or without ものだ）。」「嬉し**い**ことは、時が経っても忘れない（ものだ）。」 both sound okay. (You don't say 「嬉しかった**の**は/嬉しい**の**は、時が経っても忘れない」. Though you can use の in 「嬉しかった**の**は、日本は給料が高かったことです」.)